Calculating the yf.download function in a pandas column
The script downloads stock quotes from Yahoo Finance (module yfinance). Then it downloads the quarterly option chain. Then the script calculates and adds the lower and upper strike columns and the lower and upper option ticker columns. In the penultimate line, the script adds the option Close price column from the 'Call_lower_ticker' column to the date from Stocks.index (using the yf.download function).
Everything works correctly until the penultimate line: Stocks['Call_lower_price'] = Stocks['Call_lower_ticker'].apply(yf.download(['Call_lower_ticker'], start=Stocks.index)['Close'].iloc[0])

How do I make the function work?
And another question: is it possible to download historical data for yf.option.chain?

Code:
%%time
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import warnings
import datetime 
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message="The 'unit' keyword in TimedeltaIndex construction is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use pd.to_timedelta instead.", category=FutureWarning, module="yfinance.utils")

Stocks=yf.download('SPY', period="1y", interval="1d", group_by='ticker')

stock = yf.Ticker('SPY')
Expirations = stock.options
options_chain = stock.option_chain('2024-09-20')
Calls_desk=options_chain.calls

Stocks['110_for_Call'] = Stocks['Close']*1.1
Stocks['Call_lower_strike']  = Stocks['110_for_Call'].apply(lambda x: Calls_desk.iloc[Calls_desk[Calls_desk['strike'] < x]['strike'].idxmax()]['strike'])
Stocks['Call_upper_strike']  = Stocks['110_for_Call'].apply(lambda x: Calls_desk.iloc[Calls_desk[Calls_desk['strike'] > x]['strike'].idxmin()]['strike'])
Stocks['Call_lower_ticker']  = Stocks['110_for_Call'].apply(lambda x: Calls_desk.iloc[Calls_desk[Calls_desk['strike'] < x]['strike'].idxmax()]['contractSymbol'])
Stocks['Call_upper_ticker']  = Stocks['110_for_Call'].apply(lambda x: Calls_desk.iloc[Calls_desk[Calls_desk['strike'] > x]['strike'].idxmin()]['contractSymbol'])
Stocks['Call_lower_price']   = Stocks['Call_lower_ticker'].apply(yf.download(['Call_lower_ticker'], start=Stocks.index)['Close'].iloc[0])
Stocks

Error:
[*********************100%%**********************]  1 of 1 completed
[*********************100%%**********************]  1 of 1 completed

**1 Failed download:
['CALL_LOWER_TICKER']: ValueError('The truth value of a DatetimeIndex is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------**
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
File <timed exec>:19

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1191, in _LocationIndexer.__getitem__(self, key)
   1189 maybe_callable = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
   1190 maybe_callable = self._check_deprecated_callable_usage(key, maybe_callable)
-> 1191 return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1752, in _iLocIndexer._getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1749     raise TypeError("Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key")
   1751 # validate the location
-> 1752 self._validate_integer(key, axis)
   1754 return self.obj._ixs(key, axis=axis)

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1685, in _iLocIndexer._validate_integer(self, key, axis)
   1683 len_axis = len(self.obj._get_axis(axis))
   1684 if key >= len_axis or key < -len_axis:
-> 1685     raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")

IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

